# Sprague Grundy Theorem

Tags: game-theory

I have been trying to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/MATGAME/ this question on spoj .
This problem can be done using sprague grundy theorem . The sprague Grundy Number for each row is calculated and if XOR(^) of these values is 0 then second player wins else first. 
I don't understand how to get the grundy number for each  row.

Answer (score 0):

**General Perception**
If the first number is greater than the second number then the Grundy Value of that row is the first number, else Grundy is first number - 1.

The pseudo-code would look like:

```
ans := 0
for i from 1 to N
    temp := 0
    for j from M down to 1
        if temp is greater or equal to val[i,j]
            temp := val[i,j] - 1
        else
            temp := val[i,j]
        end if
    end for
    ans := ans ^ temp
end for
if ans is equal to 0
    print SECOND
else
    print FIRST
```